# For a long time (future)-Usage

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence

I am looking to tell my group of long-time friends, that the meet up they had last week (which I missed) would hopefully not be the last one for at least the next several months.

Would it be fine to say, "Hope this was not the last one for a long time"? (in the sense, I hope it does not take them too long before they come up with another meet-up plan)

Thank you for all your inputs, in advance!

Comment: Probably easier to focus on the next one explicitly: "I hope the next one won't be a long time coming," or something.

Comment: You are talking about "long term friends."  Do you really think any of them will critically parse what you write?  In any case, surely you yourself can start the ball rolling again when you think the time is right.

Comment: @Andrew Leach, thanks a ton! that should do the trick for me.

Comment: @Tuffy, Yeah, they wouldn't particularly go hard on me for such trivial stuffs, but yeah, am just trying to get this right so that I do not make any mistake in a public space!

Comment: By the way @Tuffy, I hope it is fine to say "long-time friend", in place of "long-term friend". Please do correct me if am wrong.